# php - using the git command not working?

Tags: php, git, api, soundcloud

I am attempting to use the soundcloud api and authenticate my account,  and this site https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/wiki/Oauth-2 explains to use a git command from github to download the repository.  i have tried downloading manually the files but there were errors in them.  this command seems to be doing nothing : `$ git clone git://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.git` , in fact it's giving me an error.

full code :

```
 <?
$ git clone git://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.git

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('somekey', 'someotherkey', 'wonderfulworldofchris.com/soundcloud');

$authorizeUrl = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();



?>

<a href="<?php echo $authorizeUrl; ?>">Connect with SoundCloud</a>
```

Comment: What error do you get? is the line `$ git clone git://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.git`actually in your PHP script?

Comment: i ahve tried it with the "$" and without, i get the error T-STRING when with and the error unexpected T_CLONE without

Comment: Well, that's because it's not for PHP. It shows how you clone a GitHub repository from command line.

Comment: First you need to learn yourself not to copy, paste and run everything from the Internet without fully understanding what you are doing. Then you should learn some php to know how it works and what is it's syntax. Then will be time to ask questions here, when you face real problem.

Comment: This line `git clone git://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.git` should be in command line, not in your php file.

Answer (score 3):

To download the repository, you need to install git - http://git-scm.com/

After that, getting the code from command line is as easy as `git clone git://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.git`. However, this should be done in command line, not in php code.

It is also possible to download the repo as a zip file: https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/archive/master.zip

After you download this project, you need to include "Services_Soundcloud" in your application. Then you should be able to do

```
<?
$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('somekey', 'someotherkey', 'wonderfulworldofchris.com/soundcloud');
$authorizeUrl = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();
?>
```

Comment: It's possible to download it from the GitHub Repository website and this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: I don't see how there being another method of download makes the answer subject to downvoting.

Comment: I actually stated, to your initial post, that it didn't answer OP's question. You've edited the answer since - don't act so surprised.

Comment: OK. I think I improved it in the edit. Thanks.